# The right way to close $query->is_home() loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I have tried a lot of ways to close this loop, but my page always crashes or it does not work the right way. I am new to Wordpress and might have some wrong logic here.

The goal is that when I publish a post with category "weekspicture", there will be automatically published copy of the post 1062. It works fine otherwise, just publishes the post 1062 seven times instead of one.

I have tried to google this problem, but do not understand how should I properly close the loop? Or is that the problem anyway?

```
function poll_after_weekspicture($query) {
        if ( $query->is_home() ) {
            
            if ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'post' && in_category( 
                'weekspicture') ) {
                
                    $new_post_id = copyofpoll($post);

                    // Give the category 14
                    wp_set_post_categories( $new_post_id, array('14') ); 

                    // Here I am trying to close the loop
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                } 
        }

        return $query;

  
        }
```

And in case it matters, here the function copyofpoll(). The $weekspicture_id does not yet do anything, that is not mistake.

```
    function copyofpoll($weekspicture_id){
    $title   = get_the_title('1062');
        $oldpost = get_post('1062');
        $post    = array(
          'post_title' => 'Automatic poll',
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'post_type' => $oldpost->post_type,
          'post_author' => 1
        );
        $new_post_id = wp_insert_post($post);
        // Copy post metadata
        $data = get_post_custom('1062');
        foreach ( $data as $key => $values) {
          foreach ($values as $value) {
            add_post_meta( $new_post_id, $key, $value );
          }
        }
    
        return $new_post_id;    
      }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "crashes"? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: It gives an error message something like "Fatal Error: Uncaught error on line xx". I have tried to put wp_reset_query() or rewind_posts() instead of wp_reset_postdata(). Also tried to put endwhile or endif after or before wp_reset_postdata()

Comment: You have a missing semicolon after `$new_post_id = copyofpoll($post)`. It should be: `$new_post_id = copyofpoll($post);`

Comment: cabrerahector thank you, it was actually a typo here, not in the original code, for I translated some words to English to make it easier to read

Comment: Ok, then what exactly is the error message? Please share that as well so we can tell you what's going on.

Comment: This code here does not give error, just does the copy of post 1062 seven times unlike it should. I mean if I try something like write `wp_reset_postdata(); endif;` instead of `wp_reset_postdata();` it gives "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)
in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes/generatepress_child/functions.php on line 414"

Comment: Why do you add `endif` in the middle of nowhere? It's pretty obvious that you are facing an error if you randomly add such statements

Comment: For I do not understand what is wrong I just randomly tried all the options came to my mind

Comment: Is the `wp_reset_postdata();` a right way to do this?

Comment: It doesn't seem you need to use `wp_reset_postdata();` there at all. You're hooking into `pre_get_posts`, correct?

Comment: Randomly trying out stuff is always a bad idea. Please share more details about the current problem

Comment: @cabrerahector yes im hooking to `pre_get_posts`. @Nico Haase the problem is I do not understand why it is making 7 copies instead of 1 copy of post 1062

Comment: The published post are like:
-copy of 1062
-post with category weekspicture
-6 more copies of 1062

when it should be just
-copy of 1062
-post with category weekspicture

Comment: [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) runs before [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/) gets executed. From what you've said so far I don't think you should be hooking into `pre_get_posts` in the first place but as Nico above said you haven't shared enough details so we can understand where you took the wrong turn here. Why are you hooking into `pre_get_posts`? Are you inserting posts via a form in the front end or something like that?

Comment: @cabrerahector I am actually not sure what means inserting the post via frontend. The post  1062 that I am copying is always having the same [poll] (the newest poll made by WP polls). I guess it is not made in frontend. I am using it because I want the poll to be published just before the post 1062

Comment: Alright, so if I understand this correctly you want to hook either into [save_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) or [transition_post_status](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/) to create a copy of post 1062 when someone publishes a post under "weekspicture". Here are a couple of examples: [Execute function when post is published](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69772/execute-function-when-post-is-published).

Comment: You want to use `pre_get_posts` when you want to alter the [The Loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/) for some reason (eg. filter posts that belong to a specific category, show more/less posts, etc). I really recommend spending some time reading what each of these hooks do before using them, that'll save you time.

Comment: Thank you @cabrerahector, is there a way to thank a comment? I will try it tomorrow, but it sounds like the hook is the problem here.

Comment: Knowing that you were able to sort the problem on your own would be enough for me. Feel free to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) once you get it working.